# How do I move all files except those that begin with a "."?

Tags: mv

I'm using bash shell on Mac 10.9.5.  Within a certain directory, how do I move all non-hidden files -- taht is, all those that don't start witih a "."?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Use the file mask `[^.]*`, as in `mv [^.]* {TargetDir}/`. Normally, `*` itself is sufficient, but the more elaborate mask takes account of any settings that may cause the display of hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances `*` will expand to all files except those beginning with `.`; however, if the `dotglob` parameter is set, hidden files will also be expanded, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586569). To be sure of excluding hidden files under all circumstances use:

```
mv [^.]* {TargetDir}/
```

Here `[^.]` (or the alternative `[!.]`) matches any single character other than `.`, and `*` matches any number of arbitrary characters (including the empty string).